# SVG not showing in XAMPP localhost server

Tags: php, html, xampp

i had an html file where i linked svg to it, it was working fine when i was viewing it in my vs code live server extention, but as i moved it to the htdocs folder in XAMPP and made the format .php, the svgs are not visible anymore

i made sure that the path was right a hundred times, i tried to change the svg code it self as i found some solutions on the internet saying i should edit specific thing in it "imge to image" but my svg codes look like this

```
<svg id="visual" viewBox="0 0 900 600" width="900" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"><rect x="0" y="0" width="900" height="600" fill="#39489e"></rect><g fill="#222b5f"><circle r="66" cx="365" cy="476"></circle><circle r="13" cx="463" cy="119"></circle><circle r="24" cx="55" cy="546"></circle><circle r="62" cx="735" cy="467"></circle><circle r="62" cx="656" cy="157"></circle><circle r="49" cx="5" cy="88"></circle></g></svg>
```

so the thing they want me to edit is not even there

Comment: * and made the format .php,* - please show us your php code then.

Comment: _"i made sure that the path was right a hundred times"_ - so your browser console does _not_ show a 404 error for that request for the SVG resource, and if you go to the network panel, that request did get answered with a 200 OK status code ...?